# How to install the missing shared library libQtWebKit.so.4?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, 18.04, shared-library

Does any one know where I can get this library: `libQtWebKit.so.4`

When trying to launch *Clipgrab* I now get the following error:

```
$ /home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab-3.6.1
/home/pst007x/Applications/ClipGrab/clipgrab-3.6.1: error while loading shared libraries: libQtWebKit.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get it by installing `libqtwebkit4`:

```
sudo apt install libqtwebkit4
```

To figure out which package provides a particular file, you can use `apt-file` (install it by running `sudo apt install apt-file`). For the case of `libQtWebKit.so.4`:

```
$ apt-file search libQtWebKit.so.4
libqtwebkit4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
libqtwebkit4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4.10
libqtwebkit4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4.10.2
```

If you prefer to use a web browser, go to http://packages.ubuntu.com, search for `libQtWebKit.so.4` in "Search the contents of packages" and you will get:

```
File                                            Packages
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4     libqtwebkit4 [arm64]
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtWebKit.so.4   libqtwebkit4 [armhf]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4        libqtwebkit4 [i386]
/usr/lib/powerpc-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4     libqtwebkit4 [powerpc]
/usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4 libqtwebkit4 [ppc64el]
/usr/lib/s390x-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4       libqtwebkit4 [s390x]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4      libqtwebkit4 [amd64]
```

Comment: If you are required to use Vidyo for video conferencing, you also need to install libqtwebkit4 which is not mentioned on their help site. Thanks for providing this fix!

Comment: Confirmed that `sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit4` also works in 18.04, 64 bit.

Comment: libqtwebkit4 is no longer available in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I can't find this packet. :-(

Comment: This tutorial gives alternative repositories for latest Ubuntu versions:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/install-qt4-ubuntu-20-04/